# How can i find out the Database Configuration File Joomla 1.5

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I did not Create the MySQL User because I was NOT able to find out the Database Configuration File my Joomla Site.

Please let me know the Database Configuration file then I will do the next step.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

In the root you will find this file "configuration.php"

you need to change this part

```
public $user = 'root_for_example';
public $password = 'your_password';
public $db = 'your_database_name';
```

Comment: public configuration their is no filed like public $ user etc...... its                   var $ftp_user = '';
 var $ftp_pass = '';
 var $ftp_root = '';